# How can I integrate a website functionality to a mobile app and share same database

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, flutter

I'm creating a website using Django as a back-end and next I will make a native mobile app using Flutter, so how can I bond these together (share same database and funcionality)? Making what is called PWA (progressive web app)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Django Rest Framework so that Flutter app can interact with Djanggo Backend

Comment: It wold have been sufficient to comment this instead of writing an answer.
The question itself is unclear in my opinion.